# No module named 'paramiko' in docker python:3.12.0-alpine even after installing it (logs say it was installed)

Tags: python, django, docker, paramiko

paramiko is inside requirements.txt and is installed via

`RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt --prefer-binary`

in my Dockerfile. I also tried installing it with apk py3-paramiko. docker-compose logs tell me that paramiko is installed.

```
Successfully installed Django-4.1.3 PyNaCl-1.5.0 asgiref-3.7.2 bcrypt-4.0.1
beautifulsoup4-4.12.2 certifi-2023.7.22 cffi-1.16.0 charset-normalizer-3.2.0
cryptography-41.0.4 django-auth-ldap-4.5.0 django-bootstrap-v5-1.0.11 djangoajax-3.3
dnspython-2.4.2 gunicorn-21.2.0 idna-3.4 multiping-1.1.2 
mysql-connector-python-8.0.29 packaging-23.1 ***paramiko-3.3.1*** protobuf-4.24.3 
pyasn1-0.5.0 pyasn1-modules-0.3.0 pycparser-2.21 python-ldap-3.4.3 requests-2.31.0 
soupsieve-2.5 sqlparse-0.4.4 urllib3-2.0.5

...

web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 38, in include
web_1  |     urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
web_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
web_1  |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
web_1  |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
web_1  |   File "/usr/src/app/emailflow/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
web_1  |     from . import views
web_1  |   File "/usr/src/app/emailflow/views.py", line 3, in <module>
web_1  |     from . import main
web_1  |   File "/usr/src/app/emailflow/main.py", line 7, in <module>
web_1  |     import paramiko
web_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paramiko'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Dockerfile:

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.9.0-alpine

RUN apk update \
    && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
    && apk add postgresql-dev alpine-sdk bash build-base \
    && pip3 install psycopg2 \
    && apk del build-deps

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apk add build-base openldap-dev python3-dev
# install dependencies
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt --prefer-binary

# copy entrypoint.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.sh .
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh

# copy project
COPY . .

# run entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh just does migrations and creates superuser etc.

Comment: How did you get the Python 3.9 into the 3.12 image?

Comment: @KlausD. I switched to 3.12 image from 3.9 because I thought that might help. I also don't know how this could have happened, but it is very funny.

Comment: Show us the Dockerfile!

Comment: Can't reproduce. Builds fine (without the `entrypoint.sh` you didn't provide though). `python` runs and does `import paramiko` inside the container.